# wcf linq to sql error

Tags: wcf

I am getting an error returning a linq query over http to an ASP.Net application

I have the following wcf service running in IIS

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{
        NorthwindEntities context = new NorthwindEntities();

        public List<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            return context.Customers.Select(c => c).ToList();
        }
}
```

Web Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WCF_Entity.ProductService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCF_Entity.IProductService" />   
      </service>
   </services>
      <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>

        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="NorthwindEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Northwind.csdl|res://*/Northwind.ssdl|res://*/Northwind.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=SHLOMOKATZ-PC;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I created a ASP.Net application to use the service

```
myService.ProductServiceClient objService = new ProductServiceClient();
var customers = objService.GetCustomers();
```

on debuging, I get the following error

```
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Source Error: 


Line 2454:        
Line 2455:        public ASPWFC.myService.Customer[] GetCustomers() {
Line 2456:            return base.Channel.GetCustomers();
Line 2457:        }
Line 2458:    }


Source File: D:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\wcf\WCF_Entity\ASPWFC\Service References\myService\Reference.cs    Line: 2456 

Stack Trace: 


[SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) +6132200
   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +134

[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.]
   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +300
   System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +26
   System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead) +265

[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6038435
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +103

[CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/WCF_Entity_SVC/ProductService.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +9464367
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +345
   ASPWFC.myService.IProductService.GetCustomers() +0
   ASPWFC.myService.ProductServiceClient.GetCustomers() in D:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\wcf\WCF_Entity\ASPWFC\Service References\myService\Reference.cs:2456
   ASPWFC._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\wcf\WCF_Entity\ASPWFC\Default.aspx.cs:36
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +37
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +95
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +145
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +134
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3412
```

changing the buffer length, etc...  Didn't solve the issue.  The database is the sample NorthWind database

I am able to browse to the service

It seems that  **Aliostad** is correct as I recreated the service without using IIs and used ASP to consume the service, and get the below error.  So it is a problem invoking the svc from the app, I can still run the service directly via http

```
The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Source Error: 


Line 2337:        
Line 2338:        public NorthwindApp.myService.Customer[] getCustomers() {
Line 2339:            return base.Channel.getCustomers();
Line 2340:        }
Line 2341:    }


Source File: d:\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\wcf\NorthwindServices\NorthwindApp\Service References\myService\Reference.cs    Line: 2339 

Stack Trace: 


[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6038435
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +51

[CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +9464367
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +345
   NorthwindApp.myService.INorthwindService.getCustomers() +0
   NorthwindApp.myService.NorthwindServiceClient.getCustomers() in d:\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\wcf\NorthwindServices\NorthwindApp\Service References\myService\Reference.cs:2339
   NorthwindApp._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\my documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\wcf\NorthwindServices\NorthwindApp\Default.aspx.cs:18
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +46
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +83
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +120
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3954
```

Comment: Do you have an SVC file? Can you browse to it?

Comment: Did you debug your service? may be exception is from your service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an article that says that with entity framework 4 there is a problem to serialize entities in wcf with lazy loading enabled

I added the following code to the service and everything works

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

link to article `http://geekswithblogs.net/danemorgridge/archive/2010/05/04/entity-framework-4-wcf-amp-lazy-loading-tip.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

How many records are being returned? There are a couple of things in play here:

From a WCF Perspective:

MaxBufferSize: Gets or sets the maximum size of the buffer to use. For buffered messages this value is the same as MaxReceivedMessageSize. For streamed messages, this value is the maximum size of the SOAP headers, which must be read in buffered mode. **For a non-streamed message, if the message size is greater than this property, then the message is dropped.**

If not specified, this defaults to 65536.

This is only 0.0625 megabytes!

MaxReceivedMessageSize: Gets and sets the maximum allowable message size that can be received.

Default here is also 65536 bytes.

MaxStringContentLength: Gets and sets the maximum string length returned by the reader.

Your service is probably returning a value greater in size than the defaults.

So, you could try modifying your service behavior to include these attributes with higher limits, say 6 MB or so to see if it resolves your issue.

Also - remember there is [maxRequestLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641.aspx) limit which is enforced by IIS which trumps any WCF setting, the default is 4096 KB, so you may have to tweak that if you alter the above properties.

Comment: THis is not the problem here since: 1) IT would explicitly mention the error and to increase the value 2) He cannot connect at all

Comment: No you are wrong, he gets the error when invoking the operation, if IIS decides it cannot respond because of the size, it will abort the request. See code line: var customers = objService.GetCustomers();